# DFS as physical location for IIS site

Tags: asp.net, iis, microsoft-distributed-file-system

From iis 7.5 (at least that is when I know it is possible), I can use a dfs share( e.g. \websiteshare\Mysite) as the physical location of an IIS site.

For example, in a web farm environment, we got 2 or 3 servers and the site is a CMS system that maintains some contents and files.

The apparent reason to choose dfs share as the physical location is that when the editor upload a file, it will be available everywhere.

I am wondering if this is a good idea? I always thought dfs is slow and not really good for hosting an IIS site.

Comment: Looking to do this as well, but running into Windows Authentication issues.

Comment: Why not centralize the data that is contained in the CMS in a database?  That way all you have to do is deploy the files to the servers in the farm.  Everything that is maintained/controlled by the CMS should be in a centralized store/repository of some sort.

Comment: Well, I figured out the Windows Authentication issues I was facing, but I'm not sure about the performance. We're going to migrate several websites and use this design. We're going to be using a DFS instead of the local drives for our IIS instances.

Comment: Hi Richard, the cms we use doesn't allow us to specify where to upload the images. As a result, if we have several hardware instance, the images will be on different machines, which will be very difficult to maintain.